# How many possible prime implicants are there in total for a 4-variable Karnough-map?

Tags: digital-circuits

The answer for this question is 81. But I count figure out why. Can someone explain to me how does this work. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own and show us in the question what you have tried; otherwise it is hard to give you feedback.  Do you understand what a Karnough-map is and what a prime implicant is?  Have you tried working out how many there are for a 1-variable Karnough-map, a 2-variable Karnough-map, a 3-variable Karnough-map?  Have you tried asking your teacher?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $81 = 3^4$. So each variable can appear in a prime implicant in three different forms. Can you figure out which?